# Updating an existing value with the update action will cause a new one to be added

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js

## What I want to come true

If you update using the update action, the new value will be added without changing the original value. I want the edited value to be reflected.
I am using Rails for the server and Nuxt for the View.
By the way, there is no error.
For example, if you try to change the value of "Test" to the value of "Test2", you will see that in addition to the value of "Test", "Test2 " will be added to the value of "Test". I want to change "Test" to "Test2".

## Code

**Rails**
controller

```rb
class Api::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        posts = Post.all
        render json: posts
    end

    def create
        posts = Post.new(create_params)
        if posts.save
            render json: posts, status: :created
        else
            ender json: { errors: post.errors.full_messages },  status: :internal_server_error
        end
    end

    def show
        content = post.post_items
        render json: {"post": post, "content": content}, status: :ok
    end
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Target
// I using accepts_nested_attributes_for.
     
     def update
        if post.update(update_params)
            head :ok 
        else
            render json: { errors: post.errors.full_messages }, status: :internal_server_error
        end
     end
     
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     def destroy
    if  post.destroy
         render json: {}, status: :ok
        else
        render json: {}, status: :internal_server_error
        end
     end

        private
        def post 
            @post ||= Post.find(params[:id])
        end 

        def post_item_params
          [:id, :content, :status]
        end

         def update_params
             params.require(:post).permit(post_items_attributes: post_item_params)
         end


         def create_params
             params.require(:post).permit(:title, :author, :image, post_items_attributes: post_item_params)
         end
end
```

model

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :post_items, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_items, allow_destroy: true

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :author, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true
end
```

**Nuxt**
store

```js
  update (context) {
    const list = context.state.todos.list
    const selectedBook = context.state.book.selectedBook
    const postItemsAttributes =
    list.map((item) => {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        content: item.content,
        status: false
      }
    })
    this.$axios.$patch(url.POST_API + 'posts/' + selectedBook.id, {
      post: {
        post_items_attributes: postItemsAttributes
      }
    })
  }
```

store/todos

```js
export const state = () => ({
  list: [],
  hidden: false
})

export const mutations = {

  add (state, content) {
    state.list.push({
      content,
      status: false
    })
  },


  remove (state, todo) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1)
  },

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Add the edited values to the list; generate values to be used in update

  edit (state, { todo, content }) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1, { content })
  }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

My assumption was that if I changed the value in todos.list and sent it to the server, the DB would replace it with that value.

## parameters

**create**

```
pi_1    |   Post Create (5.6ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "author", "image", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "Test Your English"], ["author", "Muhammad Ali Alkhuli"], ["image", "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=gfefAQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"], ["created_at", "2021-09-10 01:19:56.889536"], ["updated_at", "2021-09-10 01:19:56.889536"]]
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
api_1    |   PostItem Create (4.1ms)  INSERT INTO "post_items" ("content", "post_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "status") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "Test"], ["post_id", 12], ["created_at", "2021-09-10 01:19:56.931199"], ["updated_at", "2021-09-10 01:19:56.931199"], ["status", false]]
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
api_1    |    (8.7ms)  COMMIT
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
api_1    | [active_model_serializers] Rendered PostSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (2.86ms)
api_1    | Completed 201 Created in 84ms (Views: 7.3ms | ActiveRecord: 19.3ms | Allocations: 4437)
```

**update**

```
api_1    |   PostItem Create (10.2ms)  INSERT INTO "post_items" ("content", "post_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "status") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "Test2"], ["post_id", 12], ["created_at", "2021-09-10 01:27:20.789174"], ["updated_at", "2021-09-10 01:27:20.789174"], ["status", false]]
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:22:in `update'
api_1    |    (12.3ms)  COMMIT
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:22:in `update'
api_1    | Completed 200 OK in 164ms (ActiveRecord: 87.4ms | Allocations: 4321)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new model after editing, then update is not the appropriate http verb, it should be post. Since you are editing an existing model, that already has an id, but you wish to create a new model, you must remove the id, so that Rails understands that it is not already persisted.

make sense?

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible to change the value using update? I just want to use update to edit the value of post_items.

Comment: yes, you can change a value using update, this is appropriate. But if I understood correctly you wanted to create a new model using update, did I misunderstand? To create, it should be post/create not patch/update.

Comment: I'm sorry, my explanation was misleading.
I want to update the value of post_items, but when I run update, the value is added and the original value is not changed.

Comment: please show the params hash received by PostsController#update method when you submit the update.

Comment: Added parameters for create and update to the question text. I just noticed that the ID of post_items is not specified, is that the reason?

Comment: well you haven't shown us the params, just the log showing the sql generated from the params, I was looking for the value of the `update_params` hash variable. But your observation that the ID of the post_items is missing is the most likely explanation for the behaviour you have observed.